# Flutter CircularProgressIndicator() not smooth when image is compressing

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

So I have a CircularProgressIndicator that shows up in alert dialog while the app is compressing an array of images using copyResize, and pop the alert dialog when compression is done. However, while the image compression is ongoing, the indicator animation seems laggy while rotating. Is there any way I can solve this?

**Codes to compress image**

```
Future getGalleryFiles() async {
   galleryFilesToUpload = [];
   Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
   String tempPath = tempDir.path;
   if (assets.isNotEmpty) {
     for (int i = 2; i < 12; i++) {
       Future<File> getFile() {
         return assets[i].file;
       }

       File temp = await getFile();
       img.Image image = img.decodeImage(temp.readAsBytesSync());
       img.Image compressed = img.copyResize(image, height: 500);
       File compressedFile = File('$tempPath/image_$i.png')
         ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(compressed), flush: true);
       galleryFilesToUpload.add(compressedFile);
     }
   }
   return galleryFilesToUpload;
 }
```

**Codes to show and hide loading indicator**

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: (){
       showLoadingIndicator();
       getGalleryFiles().then((value){
         if(value.isNotEmpty){
            stopLoadingIndicator();
         }
     });
   },
   child: Text('Compress Image')
)
```

**Codes for custom widget loading indicator**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget _buildLoadingIndicator() {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
    child: const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildMaterialDialogTransitions(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    Widget child) {
  return FadeTransition(
    opacity: CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animation,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    ),
    child: child,
  );
}

Future<T> showLoadingIndicator<T>({
  @required BuildContext context,
  bool barrierDismissible = false,
  bool useRootNavigator = true,
}) {
  assert(useRootNavigator != null);
  assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));

  final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
  return showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      final Widget pageChild = _buildLoadingIndicator();
      return SafeArea(
        child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return theme != null
              ? Theme(data: theme, child: pageChild)
              : pageChild;
        }),
      );
    },
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
    barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
    barrierColor: Colors.black54,
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
    transitionBuilder: _buildMaterialDialogTransitions,
    useRootNavigator: useRootNavigator,
  );
}

void stopLoadingIndicator(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Comment: Could you attach a GIF file? So that we could see how it works.

Comment: Try running it in profile mode to see what causes the slowdown in rendering.

https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance

Comment: And also, if you have some heavy computation beating up the UI thread, it'll definitely jitter a bit.  Might want to move that off onto an Isolate.

Comment: Thank you guys! I've solved it by switching to another package for compression. Instead of https://pub.dev/packages/image I use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress , the laggy animation is gone now! :)